# Observe & Synchronize extremely large JavaScript Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io, jxcore

actually i am working on a Project which requires to observe very large JavaScript Objects with many child objects (Client side). My aim is to synchronize all property changes using socket.io in relative. Some Properties are dynamically created, so that the whole object wouldn't fit to any Schema.

I tried several object.observe polyfills but these failed in CPU Performance because of the Data Volume and amount of updating properties.

Is there maybe some Framework or lib wjich could help me with this?

Comment: How big are you talking about, an estimate of the number of individual properties?

Comment: 20.000 - 50.000 some updating frequently.

Comment: Did you try Proxy ? JXcore Spidermonkey option has this feature implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try [Mobservable](http://mweststrate.github.io/mobservable/), we use it in production already with similar amounts of data without any performance issues so far.

This [blog](https://medium.com/@mweststrate/object-observe-is-dead-long-live-mobservable-observe-ad96930140c5) describes how you can mimic Object.observe using Mobservable in any ES5 environment.